# Making drag and drop sorting game using Javascript and HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I try to implement a game I've found in a textbook for learning Javascript.

I want to be able to sort the numbers using HTML5 drag and drop, toghether with pure Javascript.

I've tried following the tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp to get it working, but I don't succeed. I've made the exact same methods, but applying `draggable="true"`to `number-field` elements doesn't seem to work.

Can someone give some advice on how to start - and if possible, supply some source code?

I've been stuck for more than 3 hours, and the I've been able to drag an outer `div` element.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>The Fun Sorting Game</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The Fun Sorting Game</h1>

        <div id="sorting-game">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="dropable-area">Drop here</div>
                <div class="number-field">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block active">
                <div class="dropable-area">Drop here</div>
                <div class="number-field">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="dropable-area">Drop here</div>
                <div class="number-field">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="dropable-area">Drop here</div>
                <div class="number-field">4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="dropable-area">Drop here</div>
                <div class="number-field">5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block edge active">
                <div class="dropable-area">Drop here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="status">Games played: <output id="gamecount">0</output></p>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the corresponding CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(94,186,165, 1);
    color: white;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

p.status {
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Game
   ========================================================================== */

#sorting-game {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.block {
    padding-top: 5px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    width: 400px;
}

.block * {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.block.edge {
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

.block .number-field {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(195,213,209,0.5);
    cursor: move;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:  1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.block .dropable-area {
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #818181;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    transition: height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.block.active .dropable-area {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: rgba(195,213,209,1);
    border: 3px dashed #818181;
}
```

Comment: What is in the 'client.js' code?

Comment: You need to handle dragstart, dragover, and drop events with javascript

Comment: Please add `client.js` as well.

Comment: The client.js I've made is basically just the code on the w3school link above. I implemented ondrag() and ondrop(), but didn't have the idea on how to move elements around.

Comment: @user111854 Please make sure you've included all relevant code to recreate the problem. Even if you don't think the problem's in the code you wrote, if it's necessary to demonstrate what's wrong, then provide it. Don't force people to go out of their way to recreate your circumstances since you'll probably get fewer answers that way. (It can be helpful if you put a working demo into a Stack Snippet, which makes it even easier for others to see what is going wrong.)

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the "number-field" elements draggable? Setting draggable="true" doesn't work? :S